# Comparing multiple fields when implementing insertion sort in java

Tags: java, string-comparison, insertion-sort

I am looking to implement an insertion sort in java with an array list of car objects. I want the algorithm to sort by year, and if the year is equal I want it to sort alphabetically by make and then by model. So far, it correctly sorts by year, but when objects have the same year, it does not sort alphabetically. Any help is appreciated!

```java
public static ArrayList<Car> insertSort(ArrayList<Car> toSort) {
    for (int i = 1; i < toSort.size(); i++) {
        Car key = toSort.get(i);
        int j = i - 1;

        while((j > -1) && (toSort.get(j).compareTo(key)) == 1) {
            toSort.set(j + 1, toSort.get(j));
            j--;
        }
        toSort.set(j + 1, key);
    }

    return toSort;
}
```

and here is the compareTo code that has been overriden in the Car class:

```java
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    private Double milesPerGallon;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private Integer year;
    private Double milage;
    private Double initialPrice;

    public Car(Double milesPerGallon, String make, String model, Integer year, Double milage, Double initialPrice) {
        this.milesPerGallon = milesPerGallon;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.milage = milage;
        this.initialPrice = initialPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car o) {
        int result = this.year.compareTo(o.getYear());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = this.make.compareTo(o.getMake());
            if (result == 0) {
                return this.model.compareTo(o.getModel());
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't check `compareTo(...) == 1`; check for `> 0`.

Comment: Use treeSet  if you do not need to save duplcate objects